# Centering doesn't work for figure with tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have a figure with 3 images in it, searching TeX I found out that the best way to accomplish that was with a tabularx inside a figure, like this:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c}
%
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \subfloat[Opciones de mensaje]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,type=png,ext=.png,read=.png,angle=0]{imagenes/pantalla11}} 
    & \subfloat[Confirmación de eliminar (Android)]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,type=png,ext=.png,read=.png,angle=0]{imagenes/pantalla12}}
    & \subfloat[Confirmación de eliminar (iOS)]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,type=png,ext=.png,read=.png,angle=0]{imagenes/iOSelim}}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Pantalla de Buzón con opciones de mensaje. Elaboración propia.}\label{fig:pantallaMulti2}
\end{figure}
```

It shows the multiple figures, but the whole figure is positioned to the left, not the center, like is ignoring the `\centering` instruction.

Any ideas? First time I use LaTex.

Comment: Where did you read to use a tabular for that? And what is tabular ... ? Where did you read that/

Comment: Your best bet seems to be to ckick out everything related to tabular material; or use `\centering` inside the tabularx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid you're overcomplicating things. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option using `subfig`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\subfloat[Opciones de mensaje]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} 
\hfill
\subfloat[Confirmación de eliminar (Android)]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Confirmación de eliminar (iOS)]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}

\caption{Pantalla de Buzón con opciones de mensaje. Elaboración propia.}\label{fig:pantallaMulti2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As stated by @egreg, you're overcomplicating things. You can just put the figures one beside another and `\hfill` will distribute them horizontally.

Comment: You should add the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the preamble, in order to properly process accented characters (such as `ó`). Loading the `babel` package with the option `spanish` would also be a good idea.

Comment: I used your answer but with `\quad` from the other answer instead of `\hfill`, it looks better. Thanks.

Comment: @AboAmmar, if you use `\hfill` to separate sub figures, than `\centering` is superfluous :-). With use of `centering˛the use of `\hfil` (one `l`!)  has sense. With use of both (`\centering` and `\hfil`) the sub figures are equally horizontally spaced.

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating things: you don't need `tabularx` at all, because as you're using it it's just for getting a normal paragraph as wide as the normal text width.

Also the subcaptions should be aligned, which is much easier using `subcaption` instead of `subfig` (that's recommended only in some special cases) and its `\subcaptionbox` command.

There's no need to specify everytime `type=png,ext=.png,read=.png,angle=0`, because LaTeX will pick up a PNG file if it finds it by the specified name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\subcaptionbox{Opciones de mensaje}{%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}%
}\quad
\subcaptionbox{Confirmación de eliminar (Android)}{%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-9x16}%
}\quad
\subcaptionbox{Confirmación de eliminar (iOS)}{%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}%
}

\caption{Pantalla de Buzón con opciones de mensaje. Elaboración propia.}
\label{fig:pantallaMulti2}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]